# NullPointerException: int android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mCurState null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library

I've updated my app with Android L and i  have this exception i can't understand:

**NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mCurState' on a null object reference**

Someone can help me?

in the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lucagrillo.myapp/com.lucagrillo.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:229)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:103)
    at com.lucagrillo.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:153)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.mCurState' on a null object reference
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2182)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:297)
    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreateView(ActionBarActivity.java:547)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    ... 20 more
```

Thank you so much

Comment: have u found a solution?

Comment: Crosscheck your XML file.

Comment: 1. Please post your code. 2. Do you have all your activities properly defined in the AndroidManifest.xml? 3. Are you trying to start any TextViews, Buttons or other layout elements in your activity that do not exist in the XML layout?

Comment: your problem is probably in the Actionbar. but you should also post your XML file and the MainActivity too so we can understand the problem